# Android facebook invitable friends request doesn't work with limit parameter

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to get a full list of invitable friends and i am using this code

```
GraphRequest request2 = new GraphRequest(tokenObj,"/me/invitable_friends?limit=5000",null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject graphObject = graphResponse.getJSONObject();
                        JSONArray dataArray = graphObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                            try {

                                // here all that you want
                                JSONObject object = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                // get facebook user id,name and picture
                                String str_id = object.getString("id");

                                String str_name = object.getString("name");

                                JSONObject picture_obj = object.getJSONObject("picture");

                                JSONObject data_obj = picture_obj.getJSONObject("data");

                                String str_url = data_obj.getString("url");

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception=" + e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            request2.executeAsync();
```

When i run this it gives me an OAuthException 
(An active access token must be used to query information about the current user). 
The funny thing is that when i remove the limit parameter and send only /me/invitable_friends the call works but gives me a default 25 results in data object with pagination. I need all the results in the data object from the start so i need the limit parameter. Any ideas how i can make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are supposed to do is to pass the parameters as a Bundle to the GraphRequest object.

Like this:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("limit", 150);
```

So later you can pass it to your GraphRequest:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("limit", 150);
GraphRequest request2 = new GraphRequest(tokenObj,"/me/invitable_friends", args, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                try {
                    JSONObject graphObject = graphResponse.getJSONObject();
                    JSONArray dataArray = graphObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                        try {

                            // here all that you want
                            JSONObject object = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            // get facebook user id,name and picture
                            String str_id = object.getString("id");

                            String str_name = object.getString("name");

                            JSONObject picture_obj = object.getJSONObject("picture");

                            JSONObject data_obj = picture_obj.getJSONObject("data");

                            String str_url = data_obj.getString("url");

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception=" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        request2.executeAsync();
```

Without it, you'll get only 25 friends (you can still get more using the pagination system).